# Make sure embedded font asset has loaded on Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, assets, typeface

So I have a font file in my assets folder for a android application. To load it into the view I am calling it like so:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/my-font.otf");
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

And this works great, however on one device I am testing with it does not load the font, and when trying to set the typeface like this it does not cause any error. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to check if the font file has been loaded?

One thing that is worth mentioning is the device I'm talking about is currently an Xperia Play running cynanogen mod. Is it possible that it's the mod that is causing this issue? Every other device I've tested on has been fine however I only have the one which runs CM.

Also, the minimum SDK is 14.

Comment: Try `this.getAssets()` and see if it works. Not sure if it will make a difference but try it :)

Comment: I'm calling it from within a Fragment, otherwise that would work (but I suspect it would still behave the same on my rogue device).

Comment: Try the way I have written my answer but customize it to fit your fragment and let me know if it works.

Comment: Is there any logcat output on the Xperia when it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
       TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.YourTextView);
       Typeface fontstyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/my-font.otf");
       txt.setTypeface(fontstyle); 
       return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thit might a little bit late, but try to remove "-" from the name of your otf file... The "fonts/my-font.otf" should be "fonts/my_font.otf"

Comment: Sorry haven't had a chance to test it.

Comment: So far I have only had the font not load on a device with a custom ROM, and I don't have a phone handy to test this right now... but I will try what you suggest when I can.